# Can I load a dictionary on pageload and use it else where?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms

On a gridview rowdatabound I have the following case statement.  I would like to load these css classes from a database once into a dictionary.  Can I do that on Page load and then use it when the grid is bound??  Each row has 30-60 columns.

```
If i > 7 Then
                Select Case e.Row.Cells(i).Text
                    Case "On"
                    'e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-primary"
                    Case "TVL"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-success"
                    Case "PTO"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-dark text-white"
                    Case "Off"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-warning"
                    Case "Rec"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-secondary"
                    Case "PT"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-info"
                End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could load them into a dictionary and save them into a session variable and reuse that.

```cs
// C#
Session[myStyles] = myDictionary;

// use them
e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = (string)Session[myStyles][i]; // access the value appropriately.
```

You could also use a page-variable.

```cs
Dictionary _myDictionary;

Page_Load...
{
    if(!IsPostback)
        _myDictionary = // set _myDictionary.
}

Event/Method
{
    // use it
    var x = _myDictionary[i]... ;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, except on a postback, my dictionary was gone, so I had to set it outside the postback check.  All seem to be working great.

Answer (score 0):

i can use  RowDataBound Event

**The RowDataBound event is raised when a data row (represented by a GridViewRow object) is bound to data in the GridView control**

```
Protected Sub GridviewName_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridviewName.RowDataBound
       For i As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count
            If i > 7 Then
                Select Case e.Row.Cells(i).Text
                    Case "On"
                    'e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-primary"
                    Case "TVL"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-success"
                    Case "PTO"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-dark text-white"
                    Case "Off"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-warning"
                    Case "Rec"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-secondary"
                    Case "PT"
                        e.Row.Cells(i).CssClass = "bg-info"
                End Select
           End If
        Next
End Sub
```